# Count child nodes of a JSON response using groovy in soapui

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

I have a JSON response due to security reasons I had to take a screenshot and post it here.

[image]

I need to find number of available itineraryPrice available. Each curly braces refers to a separate itinerary, how to I count those tags in a groovy script step.

**Method I have tried**

```
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "air-search#ResponseAsXml" )
def xpath = "//*:search/*:itineraryPrice"
def numberOfRecommendations = holder["count(//*:search/*:itineraryPrice)"]
log.info "Total no of recommendations : "+numberOfRecommendations
```

But I got the output as 1 :(

Kindly help ! Please refer screenshot as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def json = '''{
"pos":"...",
"search":{
  "uri":"...",
  "itineraryPrice":[
    {"a":1},
    {"a":22},
    {"a":333},
    {"a":4},
    {"a":56}
  ]
}
}'''

json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
def count = json.search.itineraryPrice.size()
```

output: `5`